# There is an item stuck in my inventory in Minecraft!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

There is an Item in my inventory that stays in it's place and will not move no matter what. I am on a server so there is very little I can do about it. I am in creative mode. If I try to use the hotbar slot that it is in, I can't break blocks or interact with anything... can someone help me!?!?

Comment: Fill the other bar slots with materials and then switch to that item again. Then aim at another block you currently don't have in your bar and press the mouse wheel. This should replace the current material with the one you're looking at, if it's not already in another slot. If that doesn't work, what material do you actually have in that slot?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a craftbukkit server with plugins? Sometimes, servers will pin a certain item to an inventory slot, so that those items can be used for special purposes. Since you mentioned that you are on a server, this is the only thing that I can think of.

If you haven't already, you can also try dying, as well as re-logging.

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing on a server, chances are that's how it's meant to be. e.g. if the item is meant to be part of a GUI menu or open one.

Answer (score -1):

I had some gold armor stuck in my inventory that I wanted to give to a friend but... for some reason, I couldn't get it out so I tried a whole bunch of stuff until I exited out of my inventory and accidentally swapped it with armor I already had on so if it's armor that's stuck just try this!

Comment: Did the armor have curse of binding on it perhaps?

Comment: The OP is talking about the item being in the hotbar, so it's probably not a piece of armor.